# How to scrape dynamically loading e-commerce sites (like paytm.com) in python?

Tags: python, scrapy

How to scrape a dynamically loading (i.e loading more products when you scroll down) e-commerce website ( paytm.com, jabong.com).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said paytm is a dyncamic site. They send JSON requests for each chunk of transactions. By default the number of the transactions per request is 10.

For scraping you need to make JSON post requests for chunk of transactions. In response you will get JSON data which will be easy to parse. I just checked and the logic holds during writing of the answer.

For sending JSON requests using python scrappy

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
my_data = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
request = scrapy.Request( url, method='POST', 
                      body=json.dumps(my_data), 
                      headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'} )
```

I am not going to write any code as this might be privacy breach without proper reason.

Comment: Thanks @harry. Can i use scrapy to send JSON post requests?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for Paytm Mall. Use Selenium

ptm_url = 'https://paytmmall.com/lenovo-ideapad-s145-8th-gen-intel-core-i5-15-6-inch-fhd-thin-and-light-laptop-8gb-1tb-dos-nvidia-mx-110-2gb-graphics-textured-black-1-86kg-81mv013sin-CMPLXLAPLENOVO-IDEAPGREE3950873DACD018-pdp?product_id=311698389&sid=f46b33ff-7ea6-4575-b6ea-cdb77e33fcf3&src=consumer_search&svc=-1&cid=6453&tracker=organic%7C%7Clenovo%7Cgrid%7CSearch_experimentName%3Dnew_ranking%7C%7C1%7Cnew_ranking&get_review_id=311698391&site_id=2&child_site_id=6'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver_path = 'C:/Users/["Your Name"]/Downloads/chromedriver.exe'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get(ptm_url)

title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('NZJI')
price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1V3w')
```